# How to avoid overwriting result of dict comprehension when reading from CSV?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Consider the following `csv` file:

```
Id,Country,Cities
1,Canada,"Toronto;Ottawa;Montreal"
2,Italy,"Rome;Milan;Naples;Palermo"
3,France,"Paris;Cannes;Lyon"
4,Spain,"Seville;Alicante;Barcelona"
```

I want to read the cities names and place in the dictionary with key set to 'Country', so I do this:

```
my_dict = {}
with open(DATA, 'r') as f:
  map_reader = csv.reader(f)
  field_names = next(map_reader)
  for row in map_reader:
     my_dict = { r:row[1] for r in row[2].split(";") }

print(my_dict)
```

The problem here is that on every iteration, the result of the `dict` comprehension overwrites the `my_dict`. What is the correct way to use do it?

Comment: Try using `my_dict.update({r:row[1] for r in row[2].split(";")})`. This is the method for updating/adding key-value pairs to dictionaries.

Comment: @APhillips, thanks a lot! This is exactly what I missed out.

Answer (score 4):

You want to *update* the existing dict, not replace it.

```
for row in map_reader:
    my_dict.update({r: row[1] for r in row[2].split(";")})
```